# Flutter how to create a List LatLng from a String?

Tags: json, flutter, list, google-maps

I need your help :)

in Flutter, if I create a List of LatLng like here (polygon1) I can use it to show polygon1 in a Google Maps. That work fine

```
List<LatLng> polygon1 = const [
LatLng(48.885278,2.349523),
LatLng(48.885471,2.349528), 
LatLng(48.888300,2.349597)];
```

I need to create same List LatLng using data comming from a database

My data are like this variable 'coord' :

```
var coord = "{[48.885278, 2.349523], [48.885471,2.349528], [48.888300,2.349597]}";
```

how can I convert this variable to a List LatLng to be use to show
a polygon from this LatLng on a GoogleMaps

if somebody has time to help me it will be very very kind :)

Answer (score 1):

The string that you are using is not a valid JSON Format.

it needs to be like this:

```
var coord = "[[48.885278, 2.349523], [48.885471,2.349528], [48.888300,2.349597]]";
```

You can use this method:

```
List<LatLng> parseLatLng(String jsonString) {
    var json = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    return (json as List).map((item) => LatLng(item[0], item[1])).toList();
  }
```

if you have to deal with it as not being valid JSON format you can edit the method above to be like this:

```
List<LatLng> parseLatLng(String jsonString) {
var json = jsonDecode(jsonString);
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[{}]'), ''); // this way you remove curly braces 
jsonString = '[$jsonString]'; // and then you need to wrap it to be a valid JSON format
return (json as List).map((item) => LatLng(item[0], item[1])).toList();


}
```

Example:

```
void main() async {


var coord = "[[48.885278, 2.349523], [48.885471,2.349528], [48.888300,2.349597]]";
List<LatLng> polygon=parseLatLng(coord);



}

List<LatLng> parseLatLng(String jsonString) {
    var json = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    return (json as List).map((item) => LatLng(item[0], item[1])).toList();
}
```

or

```
var coord = "[[48.885278, 2.349523], [48.885471,2.349528], [48.888300,2.349597]]";
var json = jsonDecode(jsonString);
List<LatLng> polygon=(json as List).map((item) => LatLng(item[0], item[1])).toList()
```

Comment: Thank's so much !

Comment: No its just a method won't affect the name of the variables
you will say :
String coords='[<coords>]';
List<LatLng>  polygon=parseLatLng(coords);

Comment: i will update the answer with the full working example

Comment: its updated, you put the method parseLatLng in the class that you want to work with and call it wherever you want, feel free to reach me to help you more

Comment: Thank's so much Ali,  but how to reach you ? 
And could you tell me where to place  List<LatLng> polygon=parseLatLng(coords); in my programm :o

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254104/discussion-between-pierre-jean-and-ali-alyousef).